Milvus Operator Fails to Connect to External Kafka: DependencyNotReady Error
I installed Milvus using the Milvus Operator and configured an external Kafka deployment in the middleware namespace of my Kubernetes cluster. My configuration is as follows:
msgStreamType: "kafka"
kafka:
  external: true
  brokerList:
  - "kafka-0.kafka.middleware:9092"
  - "kafka-2.kafka.middleware:9092"
  - "kafka-1.kafka.middleware:9092"

However, I encounter the following error:
{"level":"info","ts":"2024-11-28T01:14:39Z","logger":"controller.status-syncer","msg":"milvus dependency unhealty","reason":"DependencyNotReady","msg":"dep[StorageReady]: Secret not exist;dep[MsgStreamReady]: checkKafka with backoff failed: check consume offset from broker failed: error dialing all brokers, one of the errors: failed to dial: failed to open connection to kafka-1.kafka:9092: dial tcp: lookup kafka-1.kafka on 10.18.0.10:53: server misbehaving;"}

What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?
